# How do I get the time in milliseconds from 2 different string?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which I get from parameters in the URL.

This is what I have in the URL
&dateStart=15.01.2015&timeStart=08%3A00&

After getting the parameters I have the following: 15.01.2015:08:00

Using Javascript how can I parse this string to get the date in milliseconds?

```
Date.parse(15.01.2015:08:00)
```

But obviously this doesn't work.

```
Date.parse(15-01-2015)
```

This works and I can change this but then how do I add or get the milliseconds from the time??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using [**Javascript Date Object**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) and [**JavaScript getTime() Method**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp):

```
var dateString="01.15.2015 08:00";
var d = new Date(dateString);
console.log(d);
var ms=d.getTime();
console.log(ms);
ms+=10000;
console.log(new Date(ms));
```

Here is [**a DEMO Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7qjv10oc/).

**Note:** *Change your date string from `15.01.2015:08:00` to `"01.15.2015 08:00"` because it's not a valid Date format.*

Comment: Thank You, This is what I was trying to do

Answer (score 2):

This is quite possibly the ugliest JavaScript function I've written in my life but it should work for you.

```
function millisecondsFromMyDateTime(dateTime) {
    var dayMonth = dateTime.split('.');
    var yearHourMinute = dayMonth[2].split(':');

    var year = yearHourMinute[0];
    var month = parseInt(dayMonth[1]) - 1;
    var day = dayMonth[0];
    var hour = yearHourMinute[1];
    var minute = yearHourMinute[2];

    var dateTimeObj = new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0, 0);

    return dateTimeObj.getTime();
}
```

It will work with the format that your DateTime is in aka `day.month.year:hours:minutes`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library like this:

```
moment('15.01.2015 08:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm').milliseconds()
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for format

Date() in javascript  :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date
Format allowed :
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completion, you can always extract the information and create a Date object from the extracted data.

```
var dateStart = '15.01.2015'
var timeStart = '08:00';

var year = dateStart.substring(6,10);
var month = dateStart.substring(3,5);
var day = dateStart.substring(0,2);

var hour = timeStart.substring(0,2);
var mins = timeStart.substring(3,5);

var fulldate = new Date(year, month-1, day, hour, mins);
console.log(fulldate.getTime());
```